# PHP - MYSQL fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have a MYSQL full text search, matching against items in my database, which works great.

```
$select = "SELECT * from menu WHERE MATCH(item) AGAINST('$this->food') ";
```

From there I refine the query dependent on what the user wants to filter by. I have 2 filters, **vegetarian and breadtype**

```
   if(isset($this->vegetarian)) { 
      echo $select .= " AND vegetarian='$this->vegetarian'"; 
    }

   if(isset($this->bread)) { 
       echo $select .= " AND bread='$this->bread'";
   }
```

Which appends the fulltext statement, now this works perfectly, although my issue is that
if the user doesn't search anything (empty string) I want it to returns all results in the database.

```
 if(empty($this->food)) { $select = "SELECT * from menu"; }
```

Which now means I can't append the $select statement with the above if statements, and would have to use a WHERE statement instead - but that would mean adding 2 extra if statements to compensate for that. Is there anyway for MYSQL to do it instead.

```
 if(isset($this->vegetarian) && empty($this->food)) { 
      echo $select .= " WHERE vegetarian=$this->vegetarian"; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `WHERE 1=1` and then append the rest. MySQL will simply ignore this part if there's no additional `AND`s or `OR`s.

Comment: Ah brilliant, thank you very much. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$select = "SELECT * from menu WHERE MATCH(item) AGAINST('$this->food') ";
if(empty($this->food)) {
  $select = "SELECT * from menu WHERE 1=1"; // if food is empty we overwrite the $select variable
} else {
    if(isset($this->vegetarian)) { 
      $select .= " AND vegetarian='$this->vegetarian'"; 
    }

    if(isset($this->bread)) { 
      $select .= " AND bread='$this->bread'";
    }
}
```

Or am i missing something ?